# Getting rid of bottom TextInput bar in React Native

Tags: react-native

I have a `<TextInput />` in React Native like so:

```
        <TextInput
          value={this.state.text}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          numberOfLines={3}
          placeholder="Message..."
          styleName="textareainput"
          name="msginput"
          multiline={true}
          contextMenuHidden={true}
          caretHidden={true}
        />
```

For some reason, the placeholder text shows at the bottom of my app, and I can't find any configuration setting to change it:

[image: Placeholder text]

Is there a way to disable this? I've tried hiding the "caret" and the "context menu", but neither of these options seem to hide it. I really don't want this behavior - is there any way to get rid of it?

Answer (score 0):

This was due to installing https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-keyboard-manager where apparently it is the default behavior.